# Manga with a main character who follows another guy to rebuild a worn-out guild

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I read this manga a few months ago and can't remember the name.

It's about the main character (of course), who is reborn, and an entire group of people have to complete this tutorial in this dungeon. While in the dungeon, he notices another guy who, in his previous life, was a guild master, and he assumes he is reborn also. After completing the tutorial, they have to show the powers they have and pick a guild they want to join, so the main character decides to join the other reincarnated guy and like two other people to rebuild a worn-out guild.

I think the title is something like "I'll follow the hero," but I don't know. Any help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It is regressor instruction manual(https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/7u41beg/regressor-instruction-manual). He notice another guys but he had insane stat.

Comment: Yes that’s it, thank you!!!!

Comment: @someoneuseless Could you post that as an answer so the OP can formally accept it?